Authentication and authorisation using oidc and oauth
I’m implementing authentication and authorisation using oidc and oauth. I’ve some doubts in the flow. So after the user puts in credentials and gets redirected to a redirect_uri with query params in the url which have state and nonce, do I redirect them to my frontend from the callback handler on the backend itself after all the validations have passed or is the redirect_uri supposed to be the frontend url? Additionally, the server gives a refresh token and access token after successful auth which the frontend never gets.
I sign a jwt on the backend with the information the frontend needs if it’s successful authentication and send it to the frontend. Now this jwt will have an expiry. I want to silently renew this jwt with the help of the refresh token. How do I go about this?
Please mention if there are any flaws here.

Suppose you are mentioning about the authorization code flow. If that's the case the auth code along with state will be given to the return url that's mentioned in the query params, but before that verify that the return url that's mentioned in the query params is registered with the backend(it should be in your DB). Then the return url will query your token endpoint to retrieve the access token along with refresh token
